# Parsec: get buildExpressionParser example to typecheck in 2014

Tags: haskell, parsec

Here's an example from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html :

```
expr    = buildExpressionParser table term
        <?> "expression"

term    =  parens expr 
        <|> natural
        <?> "simple expression"

table   = [ [prefix "-" negate, prefix "+" id ]
        , [postfix "++" (+1)]
        , [binary "*" (*) AssocLeft, binary "/" (div) AssocLeft ]
        , [binary "+" (+) AssocLeft, binary "-" (-)   AssocLeft ]
        ]

binary  name fun assoc = Infix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun }) assoc
prefix  name fun       = Prefix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun })
postfix name fun       = Postfix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun })
```

Seems you need a few imports to get started:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Token
```

And now it fails to typecheck on almost every line.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

### Update

Errors looking like this:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘ParsecT s u m a0’
            with actual type ‘String -> ParsecT s9 u9 m9 ()’
Relevant bindings include
  name :: GenTokenParser s9 u9 m9 (bound at Eval2.hs:28:9)
  postfix :: GenTokenParser s9 u9 m9 -> (a -> a) -> Operator s u m a
    (bound at Eval2.hs:28:1)
Probable cause: ‘reservedOp’ is applied to too few arguments
In a stmt of a 'do' block: reservedOp name
In the first argument of ‘Postfix’, namely
  ‘(do { reservedOp name;
         return fun })’
```

Makes me curious about the type of `reservedOp`

```
λ :t reservedOp
reservedOp
  :: GenTokenParser s u m
     -> String -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m ()
```

So looking at the documentation here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html :

```
reservedOp :: String -> ParsecT s u m ()
```

Orly? So what's a `GenTokenParser s u m` and how do I get one?

### Just for fun

Check out this type. What could it possibly mean?

```
λ :t TokenParser
TokenParser
:: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> (String -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m ())
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> (String -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m ())
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Char
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Double
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m (Either Integer Double)
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
 -> (String -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String)
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m ()
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a)
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m String
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m [a])
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m [a])
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m [a])
 -> (forall a.
     Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m [a])
 -> GenTokenParser s u m
```

Comment: [I was able to get it to compile](https://gist.github.com/b34d44a6fab2c60894c9), but I don't know if it actually works.  You'll have to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr. but I don't think I can run it without the magic p :: GenTokenParser s u m. I see no way to create one nor do I think it's the author's intention that I should have to.

Comment: There's the `Text.Parsec.Token.makeTokenParser` function which does return that type, but I have no idea if it's what you should be using or how to even use it.

Comment: just for fun :D try that type with c++ templates ...

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @Christian Conkle and @bheklilr and this here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:makeTokenParser

Here's the 2014 version of the `buildExpressionParser` example which should be in the Parsec docs instead of what's there.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec.Token
import Text.Parsec.Language (javaStyle)

lexer = makeTokenParser javaStyle

expr    = buildExpressionParser table term
        <?> "expression"

term    =  parens lexer expr 
        <|> natural lexer
        <?> "simple expression"

table   = [ [prefix "-" negate, prefix "+" id ]
        , [postfix "++" (+1)]
        , [binary "*" (*) AssocLeft, binary "/" (div) AssocLeft ]
        , [binary "+" (+) AssocLeft, binary "-" (-)   AssocLeft ]
        ]

binary  name fun assoc = Infix (do{ reservedOp lexer name; return fun }) assoc
prefix  name fun       = Prefix (do{ reservedOp lexer name; return fun })
postfix name fun       = Postfix (do{ reservedOp lexer name; return fun })
```

Answer (score 3):

The data constructor `GenTokenParser` has all those parameters because it's the constructor for a type with a lot of fields.

The way to make a `TokenParser` is indeed with `makeTokenParser`. Its type says that it returns a `GenTokenParser`; `TokenParser` is just a restricted type synonym. `TokenParser st` is exactly the same thing as `GenTokenParser String st Identity`.

You can, as the docs suggest, pass it a premade language definition like [`haskellDef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Language.html#v:haskellDef). You could also manually construct a `LanguageDef`, which isn't too complicated; ask if you want elaboration. The middle ground is to use record modification syntax to modify one of the premade definitions: `makeTokenParser (haskellDef { commentStart = "<<", commentEnd = ">>" })`.